# Android Slide Drawer with two handles (from right to left)

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am able to implement slide drawer from right to left with one handle. I would like to have two handles (one below the other) and load different content.

I am facing the issue like both the handles are getting displayed at the same location, so that I am able to see only one handle.

How can I arrange these two handles ? I appreciate the earlier response.

Thanks, VK

Answer (score 0):

Try next widget 
https://github.com/xPutnikx/SlidingDrawerWithButtons

make it left to right, or another directions. It is also possible to add a few buttons in the handler